# Displaying sorted hierarchy rows in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by

Assuming I have this table : ( `c` is a child of parent `p`)

```
c   p
------
40  0
2   3
2   40
3   1
7   2
1   0
```

Where (`0` means root) — I want the order of select to be displayed as :

```
c   b
------
1   0
3   1
2   3
40  0
2   40
7   2
```

That's becuase we have 2 roots (1,40) and 1 < 40.

So we start at `1` and then display below it - all it's descendants.

Then we get to `40`. same logic again.

[image]

**Question:**

How can I do it ?

I've succeeded to display it recursively + finding level of hierarchy*(not sure if it helps though)*

```
WITH cte(c, p) AS (
     SELECT 40, 0 UNION ALL
     SELECT 2,3 UNION ALL
     SELECT 2,40 UNION ALL
     SELECT 3,1 UNION ALL
     SELECT 7,2 UNION ALL   
     SELECT 1,0
     ) , cte2 AS(
         SELECT c,
                p,
                PLevel = 1
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  p = 0
         UNION ALL
         SELECT cte.c,
                cte.p,
                PLevel = cte2.PLevel + 1
         FROM   cte
                INNER JOIN cte2
                     ON  cte2.c = cte.p
     )

SELECT *
FROM   cte2
```

[**Full SQL fiddle**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/344229/asdsds)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have almost done it. Just add a `rank` to identify each group and then sort the data on it.

Also, as you are working with more complex hierarchy we need to change the `[level]` value. In is now not a number, put the full path of the current element to its parent. Where `\` means parent. For example the following string:

> \1\5\4\1

represents the hierarchy below:

```
   1
   --> 5
       --> 4
           --> 1
```

I get the idea from [hierarchyid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) type. You may want to consider storing hierarchies using it, as it has handy build-in functions for working with such structures.

---

Here is full working example with the new data:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [c] TINYINT
   ,[p] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([c], [p])
VALUES (1,0)
      ,(3, 1)
      ,(2, 3)
      ,(5,1)
      ,(7, 2)
      ,(40, 0)
      ,(2, 40);

WITH DataSource ([c], [p], [level], [rank])AS
(
    SELECT [c]
          ,[p]
          ,CAST('/' AS VARCHAR(24))
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [c] ASC)
    FROM  @DataSource
    WHERE [p] = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DS.[c]
          ,DS.[p]
          ,CAST(DS1.[level] + CAST(DS.[c] AS VARCHAR(3)) + '/' AS VARCHAR(24))
          ,DS1.[rank]
    FROM  @DataSource DS
    INNER JOIN DataSource DS1
        ON  DS1.[c] = DS.[p]
)
SELECT [c]
      ,[p]
FROM DataSource
ORDER BY [Rank]
        ,CAST([level] AS hierarchyid);
```

[image]

Again, pay attention to the node `(7,2)` which is participating in the two groups (even in your example). I guess this is just a sample data and you have a way to defined where the node should be included.